# Localized dutch date format

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation, third-party-module, dateformat

I'm using "AW blog" in Magento 1.9.3.2. On the homepage I've got the recently added blogs with the date, the date is now showing: **29 May 2017**. How can I change that into Dutch like; **29 Mei 2017**? I've tried several thing I found on the internet but I couldn't get it to work :(

This is the code:

```
<div class="lt-blog-info <?php if($i==1) echo $this->__('info-first-blog')?>">
    <div class="item-lb-title">
        <a title="<?php echo substr($post->getTitle(), 0, 25);?>" href="<?php echo $post->getAddress(); ?>"><span><?php echo substr($post->getTitle(), 0, 25); ?></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="w-agoday">
        <?php
            $date = $post->getCreatedTime();
            $dateToShow = date('j F Y',strtotime($date));
            echo $dateToShow;
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="item-lb-description">
        <?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->getShortContent()), 0, 120);  ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
// based on configuration
// $locale = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode();
$locale = 'nl_NL';
$date = new Zend_Date($post->getCreatedTime());
$date->setLocale($locale);
echo $date->toString(Zend_Date::DATE_LONG);
```

Other date formates here: https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.date.constants.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this one, is simpler :

```
<?php 
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('Europe/Berlin'));
echo $date->format('d F Y'); // 28 June 2017 
?>
```

Comment: This does not give localized output.

Comment: I have tested it and it works, and why the downvote ?

Comment: B/c it doesn't work. He wants localized date. "28 __juni__ 2017" instead of "28 __June__ 2017"

Comment: But because the title was just : `Date format in dutch` and you have edited it to `Localized dutch date`, and you are not here to test the solutions of others, let him to do it himself.

Comment: Yep, "in dutch". From the question "How can I change that into Dutch like" ... he wanted localized date format from the beginning!

Comment: Thanks for downvote. Downvote means "this answer wasn't useful". It was not useful, because it didn't answer the question.

Comment: No Thanks here. and even less in my answer !

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've tried it but I got the current date in English.